# worklight hybrid app wrong viewport size io6

Tags: xcode, ios6, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

when marking checkbox "Status Bar Style" in xcode5
the view port dimensions of hybrid app in ios6 are switched..
the width becomes height  == 768 and height becomes width == 1024

seems like wrong orientation..

when running the app in ios7 simulator it's fine..

Im using latest worklight 6.0.0.2 (fix for ios7)

found this topic from 2012 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014912514
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just FYI that we have opened a defect for this and will be investigating shortly.

Comment: @idan-adar, tu.. I didn't find any bug tracker to submit it. hope it will help others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug (it only happens if the app was started while the device is in landscape). Keep an eye out for the next Worklight iFix.